# MYSQL query with "LEFT JOIN" where a.key != b.key

Tags: mysql

I have the following MYSQL query:

```
SELECT categories.key, categories.name, count(*) as itemsCount 
    FROM categories 
        LEFT JOIN designs 
            ON categories.key = designs.category 
    GROUP BY categories.name ASC
```

It does the job of selecting all categories and counting the # of designs that belong to each category. However, my app and the DB are set so that if the "`category`" field in the "`designs`" table has a value of "0", then this design belong to the virtual (there is no category with `key = 0` in the "`categories`" table) "`unassigned`" category.

My question is... **is it possible to modify my query to also count designs that do NOT belong to any of the existing categories?**

Perhaps I am over-complicating things and it's much easier to add a category with a "0" key, but for the sake of learning, perhaps there is a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: So a category key of 0 has meaning?

Comment: @Maess it has a meaning but it's not present in the "categories" table.

Comment: It would be better to give 0 a value in your categories table then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  d.category, c.name, COUNT(d.category)
FROM    (
        SELECT  0 AS key, 'VIRTUAL' AS name
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  key, name
        FROM    categories
        ) c
LEFT JOIN
        designs d
ON      d.category = c.key
GROUP BY
        c.key
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just a quick way to reach what you are looking for, I'm sure there is something smarter.

```
SELECT categories.key, categories.name, count(designs.category) as itemsCount
FROM categories
   LEFT JOIN designs
      ON categories.key = designs.category
GROUP BY categories.key ASC
UNION ALL
SELECT 0,'VIRTUAL',COUNT(*) AS itemsCount
FROM designs
WHERE category = 0
```

Comment: just a couple of little modifications to make the query faster and more correct :)

Comment: Thank you both. Worked like a charm. Time to explore the UNION command.